# How do i get array value in another page depend on my check box?

Tags: php

this my code ->select.php

```
    <?php
    include("config.php");
   // Perform query
   if ($result = $mysqli -> query("SELECT * FROM Person")) {
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            // output data of each row
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   echo "<tr><td><input type=checkbox id=vehicle1 name=ck[] value=Select></td><td>".$row["sex"]."</td> 
   <td>".$row["name"]."</td><td>".$row["surname"]."</td> </tr>";

            }
        } else {
            echo "0 results";
        }
    }
    $mysqli -> close();
    ?>
```

and another page-> action_page.php

```
    <?php 
    $ck = $_POST['ck'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $surname = $_POST['surname'];
    $sex = $_POST['sex'];
   reset($ck);
    while(list($key, $value) = each($ck)) {
    echo "Key: $key; Value: $value<br>";
        }
    ?>
```

How do i get all value depend on my checkbox record on action_page.php ? Thank you for your ans

Comment: You have too many unclosed questions, IMHO. Can you mark off the ones that were solved? That way, everyone's on the same page, as it were.

Comment: First of all ,I thank u a lot  because I poor english skill,I mean when i select checkbox(name ck[]) in firstpage which retrieve from table in the same record include name,surname,sex wheh i submit firstpage i want to get name,surname,sex in the second page ,It possible?